# Objective-C iOS6 [ ] operator overloading (const id [])

Tags: ios, objective-c, operator-overloading

i know about the new literals and accessors, like

```
id obj = [dict objectForKey:@"keyStr"];
```

is equivalent to

```
id obj = dict[@"keyStr"];
```

i noticed several changes to main classes, like

```
+ (id)dictionaryWithObjects:(const id [])objects forKeys:(const id [])keys count:(NSUInteger)cnt;
```

but what is (const id [])?

how can i make my own class using the [ ] operator

this is basicly operator overloading, which i thought was not possible in ObjectiveC, will there be possible to overload other operators like +,/,- etc...

Operator overloading is possible in C++, does that mean i can use it a Objective-C++ class?

Comment: How is that operator overloading?  That's simply passing an array of `const id`'s to the method!

Comment: While the question certainly applies to iOS 6, it is by no means iOS 6 specific. I don't think it should have the ios6 tag. Object subscripting, as the feature is called in the clang documentation, is a feature of Objective-C, not a specific runtime.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`const id []` is just a C array of `const` Objective-C objects. That method handles construction of the `NSDictionary` from a dictionary literal - `@{ @"a": @1 }`. This is not what you're looking for.

To access an object by the key `X` inside an object `something` by using `something[X]` is *subscripting*.

If you want your class to support subscripting, you implement `- (id)objectAtIndexedSubscript:(NSUInteger)idx` if you want to take integers and `- (id)objectForKeyedSubscript:(id)key` if you want to take objects. For more information, [see the clang ("LLVM compiler") documentation of this feature](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/ObjectiveCLiterals.html).

The corresponding methods for setters are `- (void)setObject:(id)anObject atIndexedSubscript:(NSUInteger)index` and `- (void)setObject:(id)object forKeyedSubscript:(id<NSCopying>)aKey`.

Comment: is there a way for my class also t be created like MyClass * c = { @"a": @1 };

Comment: Nope. What you could do is to allow being constructed from a dictionary and do `[MyClass objectWithDictionary:{ ... }]` and extract the information yourself, but it is more work, less like every other object and class you will encounter and you give up the compiler checking that you provide the right parameters of the right type.

Comment: You should add a link to the relevant documentation: http://clang.llvm.org/docs/ObjectiveCLiterals.html

Answer (score 2):

`const id []`

is just a type declaration of an array of `const id`.

It is just the equivalent to:

`const int a[]`

for the `id` type.